# Return 404 in DropWizard when context path doesnt match

Tags: rest, web-applications, jetty, dropwizard

I'm using DropWizard in my RESTful API. I set context path using `environment.getApplicationContext().setContextPath("/domainmanager");`
so that I can make a REST call like `http://localhost:8080/domainmanager/v2/listdomains`. This works perfectly. When I enter a wrong context path, I want the application to return 404 instead of any error message. Currently, when I make a rest call with url like `http://localhost:8080/pathdoesntexist/v1/call`, following response is returned

```
{"errors":[{"message":null,"code":"404","param":"http://localhost:8080/pathdoesntexist/v1/call","traceId":"26D331C92108FB42"}],"message":null}
```

but I want the application to return simply HTTP 404. How to achieve this ?

Comment: What HTTP Code is being provided for that response? You've posted the body content, but not the http code/headers.

Comment: HTTP Response code is 404.